# How to update table with duplicate names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. First one is `customers(ID, name)` and second one is `orders(ID, customer_id)`.

In the customer table, I have some duplicate customers with same name and I would like to change duplicate customer id-s in the orders table.

Lets say I have duplicate customer who has two ID-s. He has orders in the `orders` table where some orders are with one customer ID and the other ones are with the second ID. I would like to change all customer ID-s in the orders table to the smaller ID that the customer has in the customers table.

There are many customers so I cant update one by one. Is it possible?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  In standard SQL, you would do:

```
update orders
    set customer_id = (select min(c2.id)
                       from customers c join
                            customers c2
                            on c2.name = c.name
                       where c.id = orders.id
                     )
    where customer_id > (select min(c2.id)
                         from customers c join
                              customers c2
                              on c2.name = c.name
                         where c.id = orders.id 
                        )
```

Many databases have simpler ways to express this logic, but this should work in any database.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, I would use updatable CTEs:

```
update o
    set o.customer_id = c.min_id
    from orders o join
         (select c.*, min(id) over (partition by name) as min_id
          from customers
         ) c
         on o.customer_id = c.id
    where o.customer_id <> c.min_id;
```